# Android Surface view Scrolling endlessly

Tags: android, surfaceview, surfaceholder

I have an image view placed in the surface view. Code below

```
if (holder != null) {
            canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            if (canvas != null) {
                canvas.drawColor(-1);
                canvas.save();
        canvas.setMatrix(currentMatrix);
        if (image != null) {
            canvas.drawPicture(image);
        }
        canvas.restore();
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
```

I Have added zoom and scale for the image. But while scrolling after the imageview finish the surface is still scrolling

How to avoid the endless scroll? Below the code snippet for the Scroll

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                switch (currentTouchState) {
                    case MapView.TOUCH_STATE_SCROLL:
                        currentMatrix.set(saveMatrix);
                        currentMatrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - startTouch.x, event.getY() -
                                startTouch.y);
                        refresh();
                        break;
```